# TCP IP Server with acknowledgement and receive data again

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, gps, ip

I have developed TCP/IP Server in C# listening on port and a GPS device is sending the data to server.

Initially, the device sends the IMEI number to server and server acknowledges with 01. After receiving the acknowledgement by device, a new packet of data is sent to server.

I am able to get IMEI number by TCP Server and after sending acknowledgement, i am not able to receive new packet data from client. I am including my code below also. Please let me know where i am wrong.

I have tested using hercules tcp server tool and next data packet is receiving successfully but from my application it is not working.

```
           try
        {
            IPAddress ipAdress = IPAddress.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"].ToString());
            // You can use local IP as far as you use the 
            //same in client

            // Initializes the Listener
            TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAdress, int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"].ToString()));

            for (; ; )
            { // Run forever, accepting and servicing connections
                //Start Listeneting at the specified port

                myList.Start();

                Console.WriteLine("Server running - Port: 8000");
                Console.WriteLine("Local end point:" + myList.LocalEndpoint);
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connections...");

                Socket socket = myList.AcceptSocket();
                // When accepted
                Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + socket.RemoteEndPoint);

                byte[] b = new byte[1000];
                int k = socket.Receive(b);


                Console.WriteLine("echoed {0} bytes.", k);
                Console.WriteLine("Reading IMEI....");

                string hexStr = ConvertAsciiToHex(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b, 0, b.Length));
                File.WriteAllText(@"C:\ClientFiles\testIMEI", hexStr);


                ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                string response = "01";
                Console.WriteLine("Ackowledgement Data - " + response);
                //
                int sentBytes = socket.Send(asen.GetBytes(response));
                Console.WriteLine("Acknowledgement data sent!\n");

                int count = 0;

                while (socket.Poll(-1, SelectMode.SelectRead))
                {
                    b = new byte[1000];
                    k = socket.Receive(b);
                    if (k > 0)
                    {
                        count++;
                        Console.WriteLine("Reading Client Data - Count - " + count.ToString() + " and lenght " + k.ToString());
                        hexStr = ConvertAsciiToHex(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b, 0, b.Length));
                        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\ClientFiles\testData" + count.ToString(), hexStr);
                    }
                }

                socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                socket.Close();
            }


            myList.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\ClientFiles\Error.txt", ex.Message + "****" + ex.InnerException);
        }
```

Comment: Please step through with the debugger and tell us where it stucks.

Comment: Thanks Zicore for response, the next packet is empty after sending acknowledgement

Comment: You're trying to receive 1000 bytes, probably it's allready in that buffer.

Comment: The 1000 bytes is a new object and I am using it for next time to receive any new packet.

Comment: `int k = socket.Receive(b);` receices all bytes which are currently received by the socket with the defined max. of your 1000 bytes.
So possibly the second packet is already in that buffer.

Comment: The first packet is 17 bytes. So, I received only 17 bytes but still the next receive is all zeros. Wanna ask you a question. In TCP connection, how to get data from client after sending acknowledgement.

Comment: As per the document of GPS Data Receiving, the acknowledgement should be 01 as binary stream. How to handle this. Any Ideas?

Comment: I have solved the issue by sending 01 bytes as acknowledgment. The code is like string[] sendBytes = new string[1]; sendBytes[0] = "1";

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error in the program, except these comments:

```
 // Don't use the b.Length in this command:
 string hexStr = ConvertAsciiToHex(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b, 0, b.Length));
 // use k instead, the numbers actually read, not the length of the buffer.
 string hexStr = ConvertAsciiToHex(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b, 0, k)); 

 while (socket.Poll(-1, SelectMode.SelectRead))
 {
     // b has been allocated, don't need this
     // b = new byte[1000];
     k = socket.Receive(b);
     if (k > 0)
     {
         count++;
         Console.WriteLine("Reading Client Data - Count - " + count.ToString() + " and lenght " + k.ToString();
        // use k not Length
        hexStr = ConvertAsciiToHex(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b, 0, k /*b.Length*/));
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\ClientFiles\testData" + count.ToString(), hexStr);
     }
}
```

Do you know if the Poll command ever returns? May be it raises an error and you are missing that one. Check it out.

Comment: I tried the above and result is same. Basically, i want to know how to receive data once a acknowledgement is sent to client.

Comment: As per the document of GPS Data Receiving, the acknowledgement should be 01 as binary stream. How to handle this. Any Ideas?

Comment: But, does the Poll command ever return? Are you sure the client is sending the GPS data? I don't see any problem in your code, it should work, you have to debug the code and see if the Poll command returns, if it does not return then the client is not sending any data.

Comment: Oh, I see, 01 as binary stream, have you try to send just 2 bytes  0x00 and 0x01 instead of the ascii '01'? which in fact is 48 and 49 as binary.